# Abbreviating variables in R

Tags: r, plot

I am using a data set called `Forbes2000` which is provided by the package HSAUR. I am able to plot the data but not able to abbreviate each point with the corresponding country name. Here is the code I have tried:

```
Forbes2000top50ccompanies <- head(Forbes2000[order(Forbes2000$profits, decreasing= T),], n = 50)
plot(sales ~ assets,data=Forbes2000top50ccompanies)
```

Comment: Forbes2000 doesn't come with R by default.  It is probably provided by a package.  It would useful if you mentioned which package it came from.  You can find out by doing `?Forbes2000`.  But it's also not clear to me what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Yes I installed a package called "HSAUR" on R Forbes2000 comes along with it.

Comment: You might want to look at the function `text` for placing text onto a plot.

Comment: Yeah.. but I need to abbreviate the points with the corresponding country name...

Comment: You don't actually say what you mean by that.  Do you want United States to be abbreviated to US and then for "US" to be plotted instead of an actual point?  If so then you seem to have two separate questions: 1) How to plot text and 2) How to abbreviate country names easily.  I already alluded to how to do the first part.  You might want to look into `strsplit` and/or `substring` to create the abbreviations.

Comment: ...or one could consider the function called (shockingly) abbreviate().

Comment: @Dason Yes I need to make values like United States of America into US and place it beside the point on my plot.

Comment: @joran - I've never had a need for `abbreviate` so this is news to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you labels that are the first 4 letters of the country names and make them smaller than would be the default:

```
with(Forbes2000top50ccompanies, 
         text(x=assets, y=sales, 
              labels=substr(Forbes2000top50ccompanies$country, 1, 4), cex=0.6) )
```

Comment: Nothing appeared on the screen after I executed your code...

Comment: text() adds to the current device, so you would runs this code after yours.

Comment: Yes I ran my code Forbes2000top50ccompanies <- head(Forbes2000[order(Forbes2000$profits, decreasing= T),], n = 50) and then ran DWin's code..

Comment: @Vutukuri And what joran was saying what you need to run your line of code that does the plotting as well before running DWin's code...